# Template class method error "no 'void Pair<T1, T2>::display()' member function Pair declared in class"

Tags: class, templates, methods

I'm not sure if my syntax is incorrect. I am getting "no 'void Pair T1, T2::display()' member function Pair declared in class" as well as "no matching function for call to ‘Pair std::basic_string char, std::char_traits char" Here is the header file:

```
    #ifndef PAIR_H
    #define PAIR_H

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;


    template <typename T1, typename T2 >
       class Pair
    {
      private:
       T1 t1;
       T2 t2;

      public:
      Pair(const T1 & t1,const T2 & t2) : t1(t1), t2(t2) {};
       T1 getFirst() const { return t1; };
       T2 getSecond() const { return t2; };

       //setters
       void setFirst(const T1 & value) { t1 = value; };
       void setSecond(const T2 & value) { t2 = value; };

    };

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
       void Pair<T1,T2> :: display()
    {
       cout << t1 << " - " << t2 << endl;
    }


    #endif // PAIR_H
```

and this is the driver file.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    #include "pair.h"

    int main()
    {
       string first;
       cout << "Please enter a first name: ";
       cin >> first;

       string last;
       cout << "Please enter a last name: ";
       cin >> last;

       Pair<string, string> fullName;
       fullName.setFirst(first);
       fullName.setSecond(last);

       cout << "The first name is: " << fullName.getFirst() << endl;
       cout << "The last name is: " << fullName.getSecond() << endl;
       cout << "The complete pair is: ";
       fullName.display();
       cout << endl << endl;


       int num1;
       cout << "Please enter a number: ";
       cin >> num1;

       int num2;
       cout << "Please enter another number: ";
       cin >> num2;

       Pair<int, int> numbers;
       numbers.setFirst(num1);
       numbers.setSecond(num2);

       cout << "The first number is: " << numbers.getFirst() << endl;
       cout << "The second number is: " << numbers.getSecond() << endl;
       cout << "The complete pair is: ";
       numbers.display();
       cout << endl << endl;



       string name;
       cout << "Please enter a name: ";
       cin >> name;

       int score;
       cout << "Please enter a score: ";
       cin >> score;

       Pair<string, int> grade;
       grade.setFirst(name);
       grade.setSecond(score);

       cout << "The name is: " << grade.getFirst() << endl;
       cout << "The score is: " << grade.getSecond() << endl;
       cout << "The complete pair is: ";
       grade.display();
       cout << endl << endl;

       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your syntax is incorrect.

1) `display()` is a member of `Pair`, so you must declare it inside the class.

You can add this declaration line in the `public` section

```
void display ();
```

or you can define `display()` inside the class (deleting the definition outside) [I added the `const` modifier]

```
void display () const { cout << t1 << " - " << t2 << endl; }
```

1 bis)

I suggest you to define the operator<< (output operator) for class Pair; something like, inside `public`, this

```
   friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, Pair const & p)
    { return os << '(' << p.t1 << ',' << p.t2 << ')'; }
```

so you can simply output a pair like this

```
cout << fullName << endl;
```

2) You don't define a default constructor (without arguments), so you should define you pairs in this way

```
   Pair<string, string> fullName("", "");
   Pair<int, int> numbers(0, 0);
   Pair<string, int> grade("", 0);
```

or, avoiding the following `setFirst()` and `setSecond()`

```
   Pair<string, string> fullName(first , last);
   Pair<int, int> numbers(num1, num2);
   Pair<string, int> grade(name, score);
```

3) I don't know if you know it but there is a standard `std::pair` class (`#include <utility>`).

4) You should use che `c++` tag for a question like this

5) Sorry for my bad English